# Jquery Datatable : navigating to next page throws RangeError

Tags: jquery, datatable, backbone.js

I have limited understanding of Jquery and DataTables and have run into a strange issue. Hoping someone can help me resolve or point me in right direction.

I am using Backbone.js and made an ajax call :

```
var reportCollection = new ReportCollection;
var rptUrl = "/someUrl";

reportCollection.fetch({
  async: false,
  cache: false,
  url : rptUrl,
  success : function(rptCollection, response, oOptions){ ... }

})
```

And then I used DataTable v1.9.4 to populate with data received like so:

```
var rptTable = DataTable(this.$('#tableName'),{
  "ServerSide":false,
  "Processing" :false,
  "DisplayLength" : 10,
  "LengthChange": : true,
  "Paginate": true,
  "PagingType":"full_numbers",
  "Searching": true,
  "Info" : true
  "aaSorting": [0, 'desc'],
  "oLanguage" : {"sInfo": "Total Records: _TOTAL_"},
  "aoColumnDefs":[ {"sType": "num-html", "aTargets": [0]}, ],
  "aoColumns" : [
    {"mDataProp" : function(d){ return (...);},"bSortable" : true, sName : 'column1'},
    {"mDataProp" : function(d){ return (...);},"bSortable" : true, sName : 'column2'},
    {"mDataProp" : function(d){ return (...);},"bSortable" : true, sName : 'column3'},
    {"mDataProp" : function(d){ return (...);},"bSortable" : true, sName : 'column4'},
  ],
  "fnServerData": function(sUrl, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings){ ... },
  "fnDrawCallback": function(oSettings){ ... },
}
```

When the table initially loads, the first 10 data points render well. But when I click on 2, 3, ... Next, Last, etc  I get an error stating "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded".

I have verified several times using dev tools that the fetch response holds the complete collection so I don't understand why and where this error is coming from.

Comment: Sounds like you have a continuous loop somewhere. Without seeing your complete code its hard to say what the problem is. Can you create sandbox for this?

Comment: The syntax for `var rptTable = DataTable(this.$('#tableName'),{...` doesn't look right - the `new` keyword is missing. The [syntax](https://datatables.net/manual/api) is `new DataTable( selector, options );` as of v1.11. This suggests the code you are showing us may be different from the code you are actually using.  Can you provide a [mre] as mentioned above?